# Is there a SAS output data tab equivalent in Python (any IDE or any libraries ) where we can see all data (all rows & columns) after its read in?

Tags: python, sas, output

Currently I am using Jupiter Notebooks and I am starting to move from SAS to python and I was curious if, in python, an Output Data Tab like that in SAS can be seen where you could get all the rows and columns of data after reading it? (In SAS you get all data in Output Tab after it's read in)

I really feel that just by looking at the SAS output Data Tab on the go makes it really easy to understand if the code or any changes to be made to code are actually working the way they are intended to or not.
Also, sometimes we are able to see some patterns in the data too.

As far as I know, in pandas, we can see few rows of data but seeing them on the same page is a little hard to understand.

Any help on this topic would be appriciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you talking about just how you can browse the content of a generated dataset?  Or do you literally want it to automatically open the browser like the default behavior in SAS/Studio?

Comment: I Just want to browse through the dataset after it’s read in. But if possible on a separate window. Not like the way its done in Jupiter labs where data is printed below the code line. it should be separate.

Comment: Also, on the web browser thing. I usually work on the SAS Server and over there, in the application itself. There is one window named OUTPUT where we can see all the data that’s read in in the data step I run. (All rows & Columns)

Comment: R Studio might be a more commonly understood example of this - it works similarly (there's a separate part of the window that the data is "browsable" in).  I don't know of anything like this, but wouldn't be surprised if it exists.  Spyder might sort-of work for you, or PyCharm with the right plugins, but PyCharm is quite hard to use if you're not used to Intelliense IDEs, and Spyder has its issues also - but I'd try those two maybe?

Comment: Use Spyder IDE via Anaconda to see the tables more similar to RStudio/SAS.

Comment: Will try using Spider via anaconda if that helps as you guys mentioned. thanks for the inputs. :)